# 'advancedBy' API in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

'advance' API has been removed in Swift 2.0.

If we use 'advance' API in Swift 2.0, it is throwing error saying `'advance' is unavailable: call the '**advancedBy(n)**' method on the index`.

How to get index using advancedBy API in Swift 2.0?

Below is my scenario:

```
let startIndex = advance(cardNumber.endIndex, -4) 
let lastFourDigitsOfPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.substringFromIndex(startIndex)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to call `advancedBy` on `endIndex`.

```
let startIndex = cardNumber.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)
let lastFourDigitsOfPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.substringFromIndex(startIndex)
```

Comment: It's not work for me.

Comment: @Segev Can you post your code?

Comment: OK, Now i installed xCode 7 release version and it's ok. You can also do this with startIndex.advancedBy(2) for example.